# malloc / new fails from within a function pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers, struct

I have the following structure definitions:

```
struct  info_link {
    char                url[100];
    http_response       *(*worker)(http_request *request, char *arguments);
    long                url_length;
};
```

As you can see, "worker" is a function pointer.
Now, I have the following function:

```
http_response   *info_show_providers(http_request *request, char *arguments) {
    char        *test = new char[100];
    long        i = 5;
}
```

And I define a simple info_link array with 1 member in it, as follows:

```
info_link       internal_links[] = {
                {"/show_providers", info_show_providers, 15}
};
```

I'm trying to call:

```
internal_links[0].worker(x,x);
```

And the program does access the "info_show_providers" function, but it fails on the "new char[100]" function every time I do it.
it throws SIGABRT.
could it be that the way I'm calling the function pointer isn't right?  Or corrupts the stack?
How should it be done properly?

Comment: Could it be that the error is in `// some code`, or elsewhere?!

Comment: Even if // some code  was to be "i=1" it would still fail on the "char *test = new char[100]" line.  That's the reason I posted this question.  There I fixed the syntax now.

Comment: Code looks good, AFAICT. Any chance for you to construct an SSCCE?

Comment: What does the backtrace say when you get the abort?

Comment: The code in question here is just fine.  I coded up a minimal sample locally and it compiles / executes just fine.  The error is likely elsewhere in your code.  Is it possible your corrupting the stack around the place where `internal_links` is defined?

Comment: Does the function fail in the same manner if you call it directly instead of through the function pointer?

Comment: Backtrace: ~"#0  0xb7fe1424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()\n"
~"#1  0xb7d68941 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6\n"
~"#2  0xb7d6be42 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6\n"
~"#3  0xb7d9fec5 in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6\n"
~"#4  0xb7daa0c1 in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6\n"
~"#5  0xb7dacebc in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6\n"
~"#6  0xb7daeaf3 in malloc () from /lib/libc.so.6\n"
~"#7  0x0804b2a9 in operator new[] (size=100) at memory.h:43\n"
~"#8  0x0804e1ec in info_show_providers (request=0x8057b08, arguments=0x805797b \"\") at info_funcs.h:11\n". @seanmk = the function works fine elsewhere, only fails in the f-ptr

Comment: 1) Try to reduce the program down to a trivial case that you can post here. 2) If you're in linux run your program through valgrind. That bug could be caused by memory corruption elsewhere.

Comment: Does the function pointer get called in some context where you can't call `new` for some reason?  Interrupt context on a microcontroller or something?

Comment: @CarlNorum I'm trying to call internal_links[0].worker from within a class, perhaps that is the problem?

Comment: This is most likely symptomatic of earlier code corrupting the heap. Try running your program with valgrind.

Comment: UPDATE: I found where the corruption occured.  It occured in a code-part that preceeded way before this function, where I declared "http_response *headers = new http_response[n-1]" , and then did "memset(headers,0,sizeof(http_response)*n)" , hence trying to zero a memory buffer bigger than the allocated one, which caused the corruption :)

Answer (score 1):

Glibc's malloc can raise a SIGABRT if the heap is corrupted. Two scenarios pop to mind:

1) You are withing a signal handler (and you shouldn't call malloc).

2) You have memory corruption elsewhere that trashed your heap (e.g.: overflows/underflows are a common cause of heap corruption).